# submit form automatically after select image from browse window while uploading image

Tags: jquery, image, upload

I want to upload image and want to store that image in database as well.But when i click on image to open browse file dialogue box the form already submited.But i want to submit form after i select image.

[image]

Here is my code

```
<form>

<input type="file" id="my_file" style="display:none;" />
<input type="image" src="albert-einstein-bike.jpg" width="90px" height="200" />
</form>

 <script>

$("input[type='image']").click(function() {
$("input[id='my_file']").click();
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hope something like this might do it for you mate... :)

html

```
<div id='preview'></div>
    <form id="imageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action='ajaximage.php'>
    <input type="file" name="photoimg" id="photoimg" />
     </form>
```

Script File

```
$('#photoimg').on('change', function() 
 {
      $("#imageform").ajaxForm({target: '#preview', //Shows the response image in the div named preview 
         success:function(){

         }, 
         error:function(){

          } 
       }).submit();
});
```

ajaximage.php

```
if(isset($_POST) and $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST")
{
$name = $_FILES['photoimg']['name'];
$size = $_FILES['photoimg']['size'];
$tmp = $_FILES['photoimg']['tmp_name'];
$path = "uploads/";
move_uploaded_file($tmp, $path.$name) //Stores the image in the uploads folder
}
```

Comment: brother i does not able to submit the form.plz check it

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'live'

Comment: use `on` instead of `live` mate.. :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'ajaxForm'

Comment: u might not have added the scripts properly.check if you have added jquery form.js
`<script src="http://malsup.github.com/jquery.form.js"></script>`